# Get Coordinate on a panel Image after panned and/or scale Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms, coordinates, mouse, panel

I designed an application that will draw shapes in certain coordinate than convert it as an Image and display it on a panel, which it works perfectly. Also I added feature to zoom in or out and pan the image.

I'm trying now to show the coordinate of each shape while hovering the mouse on top of it, I can use the mouse event and grab the coordinate which is not a problem if the image was at it original position with scale of 1. What I need an idea to how to manage to locate this original coordinate after image being panned, zoomed or both, because the mouse event can only show the coordinate of panel and not the shapes. 
Any Ideas how can be done in words or in simple coding.

Thanks

**Update**

Here snapshot of my code

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);

        SolidBrush brushBackground = new SolidBrush(Color.White);
        try
        {
            pe.Graphics.Clip = new Region(new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height));
            pe.Graphics.FillRegion(brushBackground, pe.Graphics.Clip);

            if (Image == null) return;
            Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
            g.ScaleTransform(m_Scale, m_Scale);
            g.DrawImage(Image, (float)m_ImageOffset.X, (float)m_ImageOffset.Y);

        }
        finally
        {
            brushBackground.Dispose();
        }
    }

    private List<IShape> _Shapes = new List<IShape>();
    /// <summary>
    /// A list of all of the entities (shapes) to be drawn.
    /// </summary>
    public List<IShape> Shapes
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_Shapes == null) _Shapes = new List<IShape>();
            return _Shapes;
        }
        set { _Shapes = value; }
    }

    private Metafile Image { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates an in memory image file.
    /// </summary>
    private void BuildImage()
    {
        Graphics refGraph = this.CreateGraphics();
        IntPtr hdc = refGraph.GetHdc();
        try
        {
            Metafile image = new Metafile(hdc, EmfType.EmfOnly, "Shapes");
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
            {
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                foreach (IShape entity in Shapes)
                {
                    entity.Draw(g);
                }
            }
            Image = image;
        }
        finally
        {
            refGraph.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
            refGraph.Dispose();
        }
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void PanelMapControl_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_InZoomFitMode)
        {
            ZoomFit();
        }
    }

    private void PanelMapControl_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Focus(); //Need to get focus in order to receive mouse wheel events. 

        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.Hand;

            //Note the current mouse position in order to calculate the image offset
            //when the mouse is moved.
            m_MouseStartPosition.X = e.X;
            m_MouseStartPosition.Y = e.Y;
            m_OffsetAtStartOfMove = m_ImageOffset;
        }
    }

    private void PanelMapControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            m_ImageOffset.X = (int)(m_OffsetAtStartOfMove.X + (e.X - m_MouseStartPosition.X) / m_Scale);
            m_ImageOffset.Y = (int)(m_OffsetAtStartOfMove.Y + (e.Y - m_MouseStartPosition.Y) / m_Scale);
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void PanelMapControl_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            Cursor = Cursors.Cross;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't lose the value of e.Graphics.Transform in your Paint event handler.  Store it in a variable.  Its Invert() and TransformPoints() lets you trivially map the mouse position back to model coordinates.

Comment: Would you be able to give me a simple example. Cause in my onPaint I use ScaleTransform() method, how can I store it value, also could you explain for me about why using invert, I will update my question with code example. Thanks